# Manage bookmarks within Gmail

Tags: gmail, bookmarks

Is it possible to have some kind of bookmarks management within the Gmail webapp?

My problem is that I use several computers that are not my own: I cannot manage my bookmarks within the web browsing app (Firefox, Safari, etc.). I would like to have them **inside** Gmail "desktop" somewhere, without having to install anything (no plugin or other stuff).

Is there an easy/idiot proof way to store a bunch of bookmarks (highly accessible) on the Gmail home page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google bookmarks http://www.google.com/bookmarks

Answer (score 2):

Well, this may seem like an overly simple solution but try exporting your bookmarks from Chrome/Firefox/Oh Gawd say it ain't so, Internet Explorer and just mailing them to yourself.

Tag that mail with _bookmarks (so it's always on the top of the tag list) and archive it (so it's not in the inbox); put a date in there too.

Now, wherever you need your whole bookmark list is availabe to you.

I know this is a very simple solution, but that is exactly what makes it so practical. Worked for me for years now. And I have about 4000 bookmarks in there (yup, read that right, 4 thousand).

Answer (score 0):

It might involve more clicks than you would like but you could always use the Tasks list within the Gmail interface as a list of bookmarks.

[Gmail Tasks information](https://mail.google.com/mail/help/tasks/)